# How can I make a Debian package depend on another package with exactly the same version

Tags: debian, packaging, dpkg

I'm building a Debian package which gathers together a number of other closely tied packages by declaring them as dependencies.  I want those dependencies to be exactly the same version as the package.  Is there a way within the Debian build system to avoid hard coding this within the control file (aside from pre-processing the control file myself)?

Something like:

```
Depends: libfoo = ${version}, libbar = ${version}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm maintaining zookeeper in Debian, binary package zookeeperd (with 'd' at the end) must depend on the exact same version of binary package zookeeper, so in `debian/control` I have:

```
Package: zookeeperd
Depends: ${misc:Depends}, zookeeper (= ${binary:Version}), lsb-base (>= 3.2-14)
```

See more on substitution variables in the [Debian Policy, chapter 4.10](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-source.html#s-substvars).